# SSRS: How to Page Break between Row Grouping on uniqueidentifier?

Tags: ssrs-2008, grouping, page-break

I am developing an SSRS 2008R2 report and I have a tablix.  Within this tablix there is a Row group on a uniqueidentifier field.  This row grouping works correctly by showing one row per uniqueidentifier.  But now I want it to page break.  However, when I try to page break on this group it gives me an error since this row group is based on an uniqueidentifier field vs. other data type.

Comment: Can you post the error it is giving you? I have no problems adding a page break to a Row Group even for calculated and other non-dataset values.